# How do I know why a CSS style is ignored?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, trace

I usually trace my `CSS` `stylesheet` by using the `Chrome` web browser.

I can see that some of my styles are being ignored by the inspection window of `Chrome` - the style is struck out with a black line.

I cannot see why it is being ignored. Usually, I follow all the styles using my eyes to see why it is ignored.

Can I know the structure (inheritance) information by Chrome or by other method?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what missing

Comment: This question is too broad, it could be several reasons. Please provide more detail

Comment: A similar thing happened with me where in I found out the fact that the site doesn't support that extension (for me it was php) and was simply blacked out, I guess a same thing has happened here while other comments above are equally supportable as well.

Comment: *I can see that some of my styles are being ignored by the inspection window of Chrome - the style is struck out with a black line.* This means another CSS rule has overriden the current style.

Answer (score 7):

### In Short, Specificity

From [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/):

> 1. Specificity **determines, which CSS rule is applied** by the browsers.
> 2. Specificity is usually the reason why your CSS-rules don't apply to some elements, although you think they should.
> 3. Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy.
> 4. If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with **higher specificity wins**.
> 5. There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector: inline styles, IDs, classes+attributes and elements.
> 6. You can understand specificity if you love Star Wars: [CSS Specificity Wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).
> 7. You can understand specificity if you love poker: [CSS Specificity for Poker Players](http://iamacamera.org/default.aspx?id=95).
> 8. When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the one that counts.
> 9. When selectors have an unequal specificity value, the more specific rule is the one that counts.
> 10. Rules with more specific selectors have a greater specificity.
> 11. The last rule defined overrides any previous, conflicting rules.
> 12. The embedded style sheet has a greater specificity than other rules.
> 13. ID selectors have a higher specificity than attribute selectors.
> 14. You should always try to use IDs to increase the specificity.
> 15. A class selector beats any number of element selectors.
> 16. The universal selector and inherited selectors have a specificity of 0, 0, 0, 0.
> 17. You can calculate CSS specificity with CSS Specificity Calculator.

#### For example

If you had a `p` with class `a`, what would you predict it's color would be based on the following rules:

```css
p.a { color: red;  }
 .a { color: blue; }
```

[If you said *blue*, you'd be wrong!](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/evwK4/)

As [Alochi pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006951/#comment38888684_25007136), if you're looking for more of a **Tree View** of the styles hit by a particular element, in the Chrome Developer Tools, go to the computed tab and expand the property you're interested in.  You'll get a full list of all the other rules that apply to that element with a link to each.  From what you know about specificity and cascading, it should be clearer why the "winner" was chosen.

[image: Chrome Inspector]

Comment: Beat me to the specifity puch!

Answer (score 2):

I generaly find Firebug for Firefox, a little more featrured for debugging CSS.

Selecing an element and viewing the computed tab will show where a particular style is coming from. That will then help with the question of "why".

Most web developers are aware of the cascading nature of style shees and how that works: Inline > Page > Sheet. That is which ever is declare last is applied. What not as many developers are aware of is *specifity*.

- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
- http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/

In a nut shell the more specific the selector, the higher priority.

E.g `#anID.aClass` will overide `p.aClass` will overide `.aClass`

[Kyles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25007122/4665) has more on specificty

Comment: I found the overriding factor by considering specialty rule as your answers, thank you. Anyway it would be better if there is a hierarchy viewer for styles.

Comment: @user3282183 - You can investigate the priority of the rules in the inspector window by going to the "Computed" tab. Find the relevant property and click the grey triangle (in Chrome) to its left. It will show the prevailing setting, the overridden settings and where each is defined. Be warned though, some of the information on determining priorities in the answers here is dubious at best. It's not simple to un-pick, but understanding what is specificity, what is the [*cascade*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade), what is inheritance, and their relationships would help.